# Why does my while loop only go through one name in the database, instead of all of them? my program should sum values assigned to the same name

Tags: java, mysql, database, loops, while-loop

```
String name;
            int sum;
            myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT person FROM Todo_tbl");
            while (myRs.next()) {
                name = myRs.getString("person");
                System.out.println(name);
                sum = 0;
                ResultSet myRs2 = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT duration FROM Todo_tbl WHERE person ='" + name + "' ");
                while (myRs2.next()) {
                    sum += (int) myRs2.getInt("duration");
                    JList<Integer> list2 = new JList<>();
                }
                dfduration.addElement(sum);
            }
```

That is the code I use, the problem is that the loop only goes through one name and closes after. I am not sure why, the code is supposed to go through all the names in the database and sum the values assigned to the same name.
I will be so grateful for any help!

Comment: Is this being called within a try catch block? If so ,is an exception thrown? And how are you handling exceptions?

Comment: And have you considered using a single SQL query rather than nesting? What about using prepared statements?

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to use two `ResultSet`s generated by the same `Statement` in interleaving fashion.  This will not work.  As [the API docs for `java.sql.Statement`](http://%20https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html) put it:

> By default, only one `ResultSet` object per `Statement` object can be open
> at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one `ResultSet` object is
> interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated
> by different `Statement` objects. All execution methods in the `Statement`
> interface implicitly close a current `ResultSet` object of the statement
> if an open one exists.

Thus, as soon as you perform the `myStmt.executeQuery()` inside the inner loop, the `ResultSet` to which `myRs` refers is closed.  The next call to `myRs.next()` therefore returns `false`, and no further loop iterations are performed.

I suggest a different query:

```sql
SELECT person, duration FROM Todo_tbl ORDER BY person
```

Then use a single loop over the results.  Aside from not requiring multiple `Statements`, it would use only one query, which is much more efficient.

Alternatively, leave out the `ORDER BY` clause, and perform the grouping by person on the Java side, with the help of a `Map`.

On the other hand, if all you want to do is get the sum of all of each person's durations (the code presented does nothing else, but maybe you want the individual points for some purpose not reflected in the question) then the best alternative would probably be to make the database do the work:

```sql
SELECT person, SUM(duration) as total_duration FROM Todo_tbl GROUP BY person
```

Any way around, details of how to write the appropriate loop for handling those results are left as an exercise.

Comment: sorry, one more question - do you know how to update the table with total_duration each time the Todo_tbl is updated? I mean that each time that I add new data to the Todo_tbl, I would like it to be included in the total_duration

Comment: @HannaFrankowska, I take you to be referring to the aggregate query I presented, involving `SUM(duration) as total_duration`.  In that query, each person's `total_duration` is computed when the query is executed.  It is not stored persistently, so you don't need to do anything to get the current total for each person each time you execute the query.